# Confusing lines in shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

I have SHP of lines extracted from AutoCAD drawing, but the problem is that the end of the cables are not “Confused” (see picture below).

[image]

The result should be something like this [2 separated line but they have the same end (confused end)].

[image]

Since I have lot of lines to do I can’t do it manually.

Is there a way to do this automatically in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Are they the same in Autocad ?

Comment: i tried to make them confused in autocad but it is impossible because i have lot of data to deal with ( lot of lines ) so is there a way to do it faster in qgis or arcmap or FME . the goal is to make the end of every line confused with the start of the other line with out merging them.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcMap you can try tool [Integrate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm):

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

Set the `cluster_tolerance` variable as small as possible, just a bit bigger than the gaps in the lines.

Be sure to backup your data prior to running the tool since it will modify you data.

Comment: hello;
thank you for your answear but i did not know how to use this fonction . when i copy the python code it show this error below:

Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 16, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2335, in CopyFeatures     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset vegtype does not exist or is not supported  
>>>

Comment: can you please tell me where i can find it in arcmap ( screen print if possible).
thank you in Advance

Comment: Geoprocessing Menu - Search For Tools - Integrate

Comment: it did not work ! because i cant change the lines i need them to stay the same [ as data] , is there any other ay to do this with Qgis maybe